# If I've got two java classes(A and B), how do I ensure that A compiles for sure before B does?

Tags: java, compilation

Is there any way of to ensure a specific compilation order of classes in Java? Both classes can be in different files. And is there a way to do it without modifying the code of the classes?

Comment: Why would you ever need to ensure that? If class `A` is being used by class `B`, it is the compilers job to figure that out.

Comment: Is there any reason for doing so?

Comment: You probably think of Java code being executed somehow sequentially, and for that reason, want something to be before the other. But, it is not the case.

Comment: javac figures out dependencies itself.. if you really want to do this and your classes are in different files, then you can write a simple makefile( loads of tutorials online) or use any standard build system (e.g. maven or ant) to force compilation in the order you want

Comment: There is no specific reason. I'm just wondering if there's any facility for programmers to explicitly control compilation order. If I were to write a java makefile, is it possible to control compilation order? For C makefiles, I could list dependencies, but I don't think I could control the order in which dependencies were compiled. Is it possible to write java makefiles that list a specific compilation order? I should probably search for a java makefile tutorial. Eclipse has made me a spoiled child.

Comment: @InfiniteLoop for java, most of the time Maven or Ant are used. I can't stand XML and I like ruby so I use buildr, it's not terribly popular though and it's hard to find resources on it (though for simple builds, it's intuitive enough anyway).

Comment: Hmm, I've never really written an ANT script before. But I don't wanna use xml. Will probably stick to makefiles.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you don't.

Either:

- recompile all of the ".java" files with one invocation of `javac`,
- use a Java build tool (e.g. Ant or Maven) and let *it* sort all of that stuff for you, or
- leave it to the IDE.